# DX11 Shader reflection fails when constant buffer is bound to a fixed slot

Tags: c++, shader, directx-11

I ran into a strange problem when parsing the info gained from D3DReflect().

```
        ID3D11ShaderReflectionConstantBuffer *pConstantBuffer = _pReflector->GetConstantBufferByIndex (ib_desc.BindPoint);
        if (pConstantBuffer == nullptr)
        {
            return E_FAIL;
        }           

        D3D11_SHADER_BUFFER_DESC cb_desc;

        if ((Result = pConstantBuffer->GetDesc(&cb_desc)) != S_OK)
        {
            MessageBoxW(GetDesktopWindow(), DXGetErrorStringW(Result), L"ERROR", MB_OK);
            return Result;
        }
```

When I try to obtain the shader buffer description using GetDesc() it returns E_FAIL if I manually set the constant buffer slot in the shader:

```
cbuffer CBBakeOverlayVS : register(b1)
{
    float4 OutScaleOffset; 
    float4 UVScaleOffset;
    float4 Rotation;
};
```

The D3DCompile and D3DReflect work as expected with and without " : register(b1)". ID3D11ShaderReflectionConstantBuffer::GetDesc works fine if I let the compiler assign the bind point.

Did anyone experience the same problem? Or is just that the Reflection lacks this feature for fixed bind points?

Thanks in advance!
Fabian

Edit:
I also found out that GetDesc fails as soon as there is a constant buffer with fixed slot included in any other header even if the constant buffer is unused/unreferenced and D3D11_SHADER_DESC ConstantBuffers reflects the number of used cbuffers in the shader (only one for my shader).